Rna subtype iterative redefining
I am working on older Blender version, so maybe things have changed since 2.63, however I am asking for help tracking the rna subtype pathways, specifically since there is a second bl_rna under the ops path.
Maybe You are familiar with the android demo and it's problems?
I am at my wits end to the point of just compiling the build from the repo myself to hook bpy.ops.[ctx].[op].get_rna().bl_rna to the end of tracking and graphing subsequent ops, if I am gonna give the time to that end I might as well compile latest version stripped down.
..

We are not Blender developers. This site is about usage of Blender, not compiling it. You are very unlikely to find help with that here AFAIK.

I'm still gonna doe

I found an alternative route to tracing executions, it stems ironically from halting the UI entirely.
Just registering a class to invoke(self,context,event) with context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self) to run modal(self,context,event). starting from a rpl stdio then at least it runs in tandem with a custom script stdio operator but the UI doesn't respond until the modal acquires an event to stop the operator. so iteratively I can check bpy.context.active_operator to catch a new execute after any event sent.
I am still trying to get it to start after startup via -P for no single touch event which as it is floods logcat.

Thanks for the answer, although a bit of code would help understand it better ;) Be aware that while a modal operator runs, the autosave feature is disabled which can be a dealbreaker for some workflows

I am gonna make an addition to the Java/python side of the blender demo for Android along these lines of tracing on GitHub.com/berocl33/
